# Scene background from camera - FPS

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, avcapturedevice

I can use `AVCaptureDevice` as `background`.`contents` of `SCNScene`. And it works, but there is one problem with it. I would like to use video format that has resolution 1920x1080, and `60 FPS`. But I can clearly see, that different format is used, it is `30 FPS`. I am configuring used device before applying it to `background`, but somehow `SCNScene` is changing it. `SceneView` itself works in `60 FPS`, but camera preview is a different story. Can I somehow force `SCNScene` to use video format I choose?
I know I could just add layer with camera preview under `SceneView`, but I have reasons why this approach is not working correctly, so I need to use this `background` property od the `scene`.

Sample project is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b820wxlg8voya58/SampleApp.zip?dl=1

In terminal you can clearly see, that after starting SceneView active format for device changes:

```
Selected format is:
<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x282d58d00 'vide'/'420v' 1280x 720, { 3- 60 fps}, HRSI:4096x2304, fov:58.632, supports vis, max zoom:120.00 (upscales @2.91), AF System:2, ISO:23.0-736.0, SS:0.000013-0.333333>
2018-10-10 14:47:35.009890+0200 SampleApp[6799:1110910] [SceneKit] Error: Could not get pixel buffer (CVPixelBufferRef)
Format after 3 seconds is:
<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x282d58fb0 'vide'/'420v' 1920x1080, { 3- 30 fps}, HRSI:4096x2304, fov:58.632, supports vis, max zoom:16.00 (upscales @1.94), AF System:2, ISO:23.0-736.0, SS:0.000013-0.333333>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "video format"? What seems to indicate that the view is rendering at 60fps and the video only at 30fps? Do you have a test app that shows the issue?

Comment: I added sample project. Please run on real device. Scene is rendering in 60 FPS, you can see this in statistics below. As for video, first - you can clearly see the difference between 30-60 fps, and besides this I can print current activeFormat of capture device, and it shows to be changed.